# Array initialization in c++?

Tags: c++

```
int main()
{
    clrscr();
    int x[3];
    int n;
    cout<<"Enter the array size= ";
    cin>>n;
    cout<<"Enter the elements for array= ";
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin>>x[i] ;
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cout<<"x["<<i<<"]="<<x[i]<<"\n";
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

When m trying the same logic in c# then I got the right output as if I enter the size of array more than I initialize it gives the exception. But in c++ m not getting any type of error neither on compilation time nor at run time. But according to rule it should be give some error at run time in output if i give array size more than I initialize. And one thing more why it determine the 09 as two numbrs not single as 90 it shows it 0 and 9 at differect index as in output.

[image: output]

[image]

Comment: Format your post please. Three months is long enough to have learned how to post questions.

Comment: sorry i tried but due to network problem it could not be.

Comment: Network problems? If you could write the post with broken formatting, you could write it with non-broken formatting. As far as I can tell, you've _never_ formatted code in your posts; someone else has always done it for you.

Comment: This is a reasonably low-quality question, but I don't see how it's "ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical" or "cannot be reasonably answered in its current form". It's quite clear what the question is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have an array:

```
char array[3];
```

And you try to write into an element that doesn't exist:

```
array[15] = '!';
```

Then this *is* an error. However, a compiler is not required by the C++ Standard to diagnose this error, and most do not. This is because it would require computation *every time you accessed the array* to determine whether you were within the array bounds.

Instead, **it is up to the programmer to ensure that he/she uses the array correctly**, by writing these bounds checks his- or herself. Then the checks are only performed when the programmer has deemed them necessary, and there are no wasted computations.

So:

```
std::cin >> n;

if (n > 3)
   throw std::runtime_error("OMG not enough space in my array!");
```

Comment: +1. To get bounds checking, switch to `std::vector` and index with `at` rather `operator[]`.

Comment: @larsmans: If he switches to `std::vector`, he might as well allow as many elements as he likes; no bounds-checking needed.

Comment: and what about the nos. as I insert 09 then it show 0 and 9 on seprate indexes and on 7th index there should 0 why is 6 there according to output.

Comment: @avirk: Why should the 7th element be 0? There _is no 7th element_. You're reading from invalid memory. The issues you have with items not being what you expect is all because you're writing and reading from invalid elements.

Comment: If there is no 7th element according to the compiler then why it prints the 4th index 78?

Comment: @avirk: Undefined Behaviour. It's probably just whatever's in memory, at a location that you're not allowed to read.

Comment: one more thing why it seprate 09 as 0 and 9 its still out of understanig.

Comment: @avirk: The issues you have with items not being what you expect is all because you're writing and reading from invalid elements.

Comment: I edited the my question and as you can see the screen shot of the ouput its still behaving the same. Even I have input the size of array what I had initialized.

Comment: I edited the my question and as you can see the screen shot of the ouput its still behaving the same. Even I have input the size of array what I had initialized.

Comment: @avirk: It might be that `cin` is expecting you to never input a number with leading zeroes. A number without leading zeroes doesn't look like `09`, but `9`. So it assumes `0` is a distinct integer.

Answer (score 0):

C++ and in-turn C are not required to throw an exception when you over-run an array.  Arrays are simply memory blocks, and when you over-run them, the only time you will encounter an error is when you have exceeded the bounds of what the operating system run-time allows you to access as a user in memory.  For instance, if you over-ran your array, and wrote over the values for the return pointer for your function, and then when the function returns, it tries to place in the instruction pointer register a bogus return address, the OS itself will throw a segmentation fault because you tried to execute code beyond a memory address you were allowed.  Segmentation faults and bus error messages though are OS-specific, not specific to C or C++ (i.e., you'd get the same errors with assembly).